# Avoiding Duplicates in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

So I've a subscription system and I don't want a user to be able to subscribe twice with the same email.

What came into my mind is using PHP without any `DUPLICATE` MySQL stuffs, so I thought I can just do:

```
$checkvar = mysql_query("SELECT email FROM subscribers_list WHERE email = '" . $email . "'");

   if (empty($checkvar)){
        echo "There is no duplicate."; 
       }else { 
        echo "Duplicate found!"; 
    }
```

But for some unknown reason the above code won't work as expected.

Comment: No, you can't do it like that. Use `mysql_num_rows()` - I.e.: `$numrows=mysql_num_rows($checkvar); if($numrows > 0){ echo "There is a duplicate"; }else{ // keep going }`

Comment: if you add a 'unique' index to the user email column will be enough to stop duplicate emails.

Comment: *cough* *cough* http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: While that works @RyanVincent some feedback to the user is valuable.

Comment: [*ahem (cough) ahem*](http://php.net/pdo) <= PDO. ;-)

Comment: Apart from reading the manual, also please write what you mean by 'won't work as expected'.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, was never meant to be just that, was more of a reminder to the op.

Comment: Because unique indexes require a length for strings ? Anyway, Fred-ii helped me a lot. Cheers

Comment: Why not let sql do the work, group by email and count, then if count > 1 there is duplicate on that email address.

Comment: @ShowTime Glad to have helped, cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql_query returns a `result` not array or any data variable so use....

```
if (!(mysql_num_rows($checkvar))>0) { echo "There is no duplicate."; } 
else { echo "Duplicate found!"; }
```

and try to format your code!

Comment: You sure about that? Why don't you just copy [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23792110/avoiding-duplicates-in-mysql#comment36593342_23792110).

Comment: `If >0` means there is a record found. Which is the same as saying `if == 1` meaning if more than zero.

Comment: @Prashank I should've waited 5 minutes. Now the proof is gone lol

Comment: @HackerManiac You're welcome. However, my personal favorite is to start with a positive, then the negative; but that's just me ;-)

Comment: if(mysql_num_rows($checkvar) < 1) looks cleaner (just saying)

Comment: There are so many ways to check using num_rows(), however I have found in some *strange* cases that using `if ($var !=1)` will not work, as opposed to `if ($var >0)` does.

Answer (score 0):

Add a MySQL constraint.

It wont allow any code to insert the same email twice.

```
ALTER TABLE subscribers_list ADD CONSTRAINT unique_email UNIQUE (email)
```